# Must Initialize Fabric before using singleton() when calling Crashlytics.logException(ex);

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have been trying soo hard to find a solution to this problem. I have implemented Crashlytics successfully in a simple app, like an app containing a simple button a text to display. I have even tested it in **Firebase** console , and it logs a custom exception successfully using the following line..

`Crashlytics.logException(new IOException("A dummy IOException"))`;

I have followed the following link for Crashlytics implementation 
[Crashlytics official tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android&utm_source=fabric&utm_medium=inline_banner&utm_campaign=fabric_sunset&utm_content=kits_crashlytics#nav-buttons-1)

And I can see a non-fatal error logged in Firebase console after around 5 minutes in the console only.

But when the app became somewhat complex, like when I used Firebase ML Vision library for some scanning purpose and a bunch of other libraries, it started throwing the following error everytime the code for Crashlytics logging is executed.

```
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must Initialize Fabric before using singleton()
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.singleton(Fabric.java:301)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.getKit(Fabric.java:551)
        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.getInstance(Crashlytics.java:191)
        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.checkInitialized(Crashlytics.java:390)
        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.logException(Crashlytics.java:210)
        at co.behtar.behtarinternal.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7341)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14226)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7307)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27796)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)`
```

I didn't have to initialize **Fabric** before and **Crashlytics** worked seemlessly in that case. But in this case when some libraries I have used, even if I have initialized Fabric in a number of ways inside MainActivity and even inside Application class too, it still throws this error.

I have spent around 3 whole days searching for a solution and in the course of event, even created a Fabric account and integrated Fabric using its onboarding page. But still no success with the Crash logging.

I have followed following link for Fabric implementation
[Fabric for Crashlytics official doc](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install)

Did anyone around faced a similar issue like mine?? if so, what steps did you follow to get rid of it in order for **Crashlytics** to work?

> EDIT

Here is the code snippet where I initialize Fabric, even though it is not required in Firebase Crashlytics, I have tried this one..

```
public class App extends Application {
AppComponent appComponent;
private static Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fresco.initialize(this);
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
    }
    context = this;
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(this)).utilsModule(new UtilsModule()).build();
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
    return appComponent;
}
```

}

And here is the code snippet where I called `Crashlytics.logException()`

```
private void renderErrorResponse(Throwable error) {
    if (error instanceof HttpException) {
        ResponseBody responseBody = ((HttpException) error).response().errorBody();
        LoginErrorResponse loginErrorResponse;
        try {
            String responseString = null;
            if (responseBody != null) {
                responseString = responseBody.string();
            }
            if (Utils.isValidJson(responseString)) {
                responseString = Utils.toPrettyFormat(responseString);
                loginErrorResponse = gson.fromJson(responseString, LoginErrorResponse.class);
                Utils.logMessage("LoginError", responseString);
                Utils.showCustomToast(this, loginErrorResponse.getNon_field_errors().get(0));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Utils.logError("IOException", e);
        }
    } else {
        Utils.showCustomToast(this, this.getString(R.string.something_went_wrong));
        Crashlytics.logException(error);
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is the error which is coming now after adding api key in manifest and changing fabric initialization code as @Romadro suggested.

```
The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
```

Comment: post code where you call Crashlytics.logException and where you initialize Fabric

Comment: @Romadro will edit my question then, here is the code where I do both of the stuffs.

Comment: I want to know on what context renderErrorResponse executed? Is this is an activity or service? What thread?

Comment: Yeah, it is an activity context..That is this method is called in an activity only

Comment: `FirebaseApp initialization successful
 CrashlyticsInitProvider skipping initialization`  . These two info message are shown at the top of logcat

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Application

```
      Fabric.with(
              this,
              new Crashlytics.Builder().core(
                      new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
                              .build()
              ).build();
      );
```

Comment: I have tried that too. But still no luck. I even tried adding fabric api key inside application manifest.  But still it is showing the error.  This time it shows this error ` E/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics must be initialized by calling Fabric.with(Context) prior to logging exceptions.`

Answer (score 0):

Swap the position of this lines:

```java
Fresco.initialize(this);
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

to:

```java
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
Fresco.initialize(this);
```